# Actionbar icon click and Up arrow click problem

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I'm using the nav component with navgraph. This is how my navgraph is setup:

**Main activity -> CategoriesFragment (Home Fragment) -> CategoryFragment -> PomoClockFragment**

I do the following navigation **CategoriesFragment -> CategoryFragment -> PomoClockFragment.**

At this point, repeatedly pressing the phone's physical back button or the `Actionbar`'s Up button works as expected with the fragment back stack. But if I press an icon in the `Actionbar` to show another fragment and then click the Up arrow, it goes directly back to the home fragment (CategoriesFragment) instead of going back to the most recent fragment on the back stack. How do I fix this? I also tried other approaches which are shown as comments in the Activity code below in the `onSupportNavigateUp()` method.

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnCreate() called")

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.graph)
            .build()
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {

super.onSupportNavigateUp()

        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        //*** I also tried these, but does not solve the problem I am having ***

        //return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment).navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()

        //supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()

        //return navController.navigateUp()

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnCreateOptionsMenu() called")

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnOptionsItemSelected() called")

       return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)  || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

**Navgraph**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/categoriesFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/clockFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.ClockFragment"
        android:label="Pomo Clock"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_clock" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoryFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.CategoryFragment"
        android:label="Category"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoryFragment_to_clockFragment"
            app:destination="@id/clockFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            app:argType="com.example.pomoplay.Category"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoryFragment_to_newTaskDialogFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newTaskDialogFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="pomotask"
            app:argType="com.example.pomoplay.PomoTask"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="fromNewTaskDialog"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="fromCategoriesFragmentTitle"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoriesFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.CategoriesFragment"
        android:label="Categories"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_categories">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_newCategoryDialogFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newCategoryDialogFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            app:argType="com.example.pomoplay.Category"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_categoryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoryFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="fromNewCategoryDialog"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/newCategoryDialogFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.NewCategoryDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_category_dialog">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newCategoryDialogFragment_to_categoriesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoriesFragment" />
    </dialog>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/newTaskDialogFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.NewTaskDialogFragment"
        android:label="fragment_new_task_dialog"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_task_dialog" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newTaskDialogFragment_to_categoryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoryFragment" />
    </dialog>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default action for the arrow up in the ActionBar is NavigateUp, this starts the parent activity, instead of finishing the current one.

You will need to override `onOptionItemSelected` when `item.itemId == android.R.id.home` and call activity `fragmentmanager.popStackBack()` method (plus handle the stack size being 0 and finishing it) **or** call `onBackPressed()`

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed()
        return true
    }

    Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnOptionsItemSelected() called")
   return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)  || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: But having the following code in ```onOptionsItemSelected()``` prevents your solution from working. Should I just remove it? Here's the code: ```NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)  || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)```

Comment: You need to add an if

Comment: I have an icon in the ```Actionbar``` which when clicked navigates to the home fragment ```CategoriesFragment```. With your code above, if I click on this icon it takes me to the home fragment, but the Up arrow disappears and now if click on the phone's physical back button, it exits the app instead of traversing the fragment back stack. What can I do to fix this, if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: ```return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)  || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)``` is causing the original problem to persist. Should I remove it?